# summation and inequality induction proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

I have to use induction to prove the following inequality:

$\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n}} \frac{1}{k} \geq 1 + \frac{n}{2}$.

So the base case is $n=1$ and it's true because both sides will equal $\frac{3}{2}$.

If we assume $n=m+1$ we get

$\sum_{k=1}^{2^{m+1}} \frac{1}{k} \geq 1 + \frac{m+1}{2}$.

But I'm not sure how to prove that the LHS=RHS.

Is it true to say this:

$\sum_{k=1}^{2^{m}} \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{m+1} \geq 1 + \frac{m+1}{2}$?

Comment: Note that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2^{m+1}} \frac{1}{k} = \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2^m}\frac{1}{k}\right)+\left(\sum\limits_{k=2^m+1}^{2^{m+1}}\frac{1}{k}\right)$.  Notice what happens... an example: $\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}\geq \frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}$

Comment: @JMoravitz That's a pretty weak duplicate

Comment: @mrnovice the first answer of the linked question gives *all* of the insight one needs to complete this proof, noting that in the $n$'th "group" there are $2^{n-1}$ terms and each of the terms are greater than $\frac{1}{2^n}$.  The *only* missing step is formalizing the argument with induction and recognizing that the original form of the question here is exactly the same observation made in that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finish the proof it is enough to note that

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2^{m+1}} \dfrac{1}{k} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2^{m}} \dfrac{1}{k} + \sum\limits_{k=2^{m} + 1}^{2^{m+1}} \dfrac{1}{k}$$

The first part of the sum in the right side is $\geqslant 1+\dfrac{m}{2}$, the other one is $\geqslant \sum\limits_{k=2^{m} + 1}^{2^{m+1}} \dfrac{1}{k} \geqslant 2^m \cdot \dfrac{1}{2^{m + 1}} = \dfrac{1}{2}$, so, overall,
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2^{m+1}} \dfrac{1}{k} \geqslant 1+ \dfrac{m + 1}{2}$$
which completes your proof by induction.

Comment: You have an error.  $\sum\limits_{k=2^{m} + 1}^{2^{m+1}} \dfrac{1}{k} < 2^m \cdot \dfrac{1}{2^m}$.  The summand you want to replace by is not $\frac{1}{2^m}$ but rather $\frac{1}{2^{m+1}}$

Comment: @JMoravitz, good spot, thanks! Fixed now.